# Cookie length should be less then or equal to 4096 characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

Chrome dev tools has started warning me that "Cookie length should be less then or equal to 4096 characters" (spelling mistake and all).

Trouble is, my cookie is only ~1100 characters.

However, and I think this may be the cause, the cookie is being set 7 times over the lifetime of the request.

So browser bug or should I hack Codeigniter to not set it 7 times?

Below is a portion of my response header (actual values replaced with random strings) :-

```
Set-Cookie:cms_session=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; expires=Fri, 07-Apr-2017 20:20:36 GMT; Max-Age=28800; path=/
Set-Cookie:cms_session=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; expires=Fri, 07-Apr-2017 20:20:36 GMT; Max-Age=28800; path=/
Set-Cookie:cms_session=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; expires=Fri, 07-Apr-2017 20:20:36 GMT; Max-Age=28800; path=/
Set-Cookie:cms_session=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; expires=Fri, 07-Apr-2017 20:20:36 GMT; Max-Age=28800; path=/
Set-Cookie:cms_session=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; expires=Fri, 07-Apr-2017 20:20:36 GMT; Max-Age=28800; path=/
Set-Cookie:cms_session=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; expires=Fri, 07-Apr-2017 20:20:36 GMT; Max-Age=28800; path=/
Set-Cookie:cms_session=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; expires=Fri, 07-Apr-2017 20:20:36 GMT; Max-Age=28800; path=/
```

Comment: where you are setting the cookies? any code snippet?

Comment: You're using CI2, which was abandoned over 18 months ago. Upgrade, and the problem will go away.

Comment: I can't upgrade right now (deadlines etc.).

Comment: You're 18 months past the deadline already. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't feel like hacking CI2 so I used the DB method for session handling so that it would only set the cookie once.